# How can I break this circular dependence between these two javascript modules?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, node-modules, circular-dependency

How can I break the circular dependence between these two modules?  Specifically, `assignedDoctors: [Doctor.Schema]` in the patient model, and `assignedPatients: [Patient.Schema]` in the doctor model.

```
/* Patient model */
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Notification = require('./notification')
const Appointment = require('./appointment')
const Doctor = require('./doctor')
const Medication = require('./medication')

const PatientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        userId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: [true, "Missing user id."]
        },
        notifications: [Notification.schema],
        appointments: [Appointment.schema],
        assignedDoctors: [Doctor.schema],
        medications: [Medication.schema]
});

const Patient = mongoose.model("Patient", PatientSchema);

module.exports = { Patient };
```

---

```
/* Doctor model */
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { Notification } = require('./notification')
const { Appointment } = require('./appointment')
const { Patient } = require('./patient')

const DoctorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        userId: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                required: [true, "Missing user id."]
        },
        specialty: String,
        notifications: [Notification.schema],
        assignedPatients: [Patient.schema],
        appointments: [Appointment.schema],
});    

const Doctor = mongoose.model("Doctor", DoctorSchema);

module.exports = { Doctor };
```

Someone suggested that I can solve it by introducing a third module file, but I am not sure what is it exactly I need to do.  Can someone please show me?

Comment: circular dependencies in code are resolved by creating third module which both module depend on. I aloso recommend to [watch this](https://youtu.be/TMuno5RZNeE?t=1741).

Comment: Someone else also suggested that but I want to know what exactly is it that i need to do to do to break the circular dependence.